# How do I get this simple PWM example to work?

Tags: msp430, pwm

I am just starting to work with the MSP430 microcontrollers after previously only working with STM32, and as I am still a beginner with all of this, the change is quite a lot, but I am struggling to get a simple PWM output working.

At the office, we had a spare dev board around, so I am using this. It is the MSP-TS430PZ100B ([USER GUIDE](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau278af/slau278af.pdf?ts=1591604538729&ref_url=https://www.ti.com/tool/MSP-TS430PZ100), page 142-144) and the specific microcontroller being used is the [MSP430F6736](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slas731d/slas731d.pdf?ts=1591604488221&ref_url=https://www.google.com/). The pin descriptions for the package I am using starts on page 12.

I am following a simple PWM example program that I found [HERE](https://www.kompulsa.com/example-code-msp430-pwm/). However, I have changed the output pin. Looking at the datasheet for the microcontroller I am using, timer TA0 is default mapped to P1.0 and P1.1, so instead of using P1.2 like the example, I have changed it to P1.0 (P1.0 is also where the on-board LED is located too).

So, the code I have looks like this:

```
#include <msp430.h> 

int main(void) {

    WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD; //Disable the Watchdog timer

    P1DIR |= BIT0; //Set pin 1.0 to the output direction.
    P1SEL |= BIT0; //Select pin 1.0 as PWM output.

    TA0CCR0 = 1000-1;             // PWM Period
    TA0CCTL1 = OUTMOD_7;          // CCR1 reset/set
    TA0CCR1 = 250;                // CCR1 PWM duty cycle
    TA0CTL = TASSEL_2 + MC_1;   // SMCLK, up mode
}
```

So I program the microcontroller and nothing happens. I have put an oscilloscope on the output and there is not even a flicker. Just stays at 0V. The pin works fine as an output, when I write a simple program to toggle the port opn/off manually, it works fine, but when trying this simple example program, I get absolutely nothing.

I assume I am overlooking something simple, but I just cannot seem to see it. What is it I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure pin 1.0 is available to use for PWM?

Comment: @HeadCode I gave a link to the datasheet. The pin description part isn't far into it, but I will edit the question and mention the page number too. But yes, P1.0 seems to me like it should be available as it has TA0 default mapped to pins 1.0 and 1.1

Comment: I wish I had more time to look at this, but have you tried TA0CCR0 instead of TA0CCR1? Page 73 leads me to believe you have the wrong register.

Comment: @HeadCode I use both. I use TA0CCR0 at the beginning of the PWM cycle. Page 73 is the pin map?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good, except you need to add a sleep function or simply add a forever loop like **while (1) __no_operation();** at the end to keep the processor from executing the exit code, which may cause reset and explain why you don't see anything.